# Convert Array of string to a number (int or float)

Tags: php, arrays

I have this array

```
Array
(
    [0] => Mytestarray

    [1] => 10

    [2] => 2

    [3] => 26

    [4] => 2

    [5] => 1.875.12,00

    [6] => 2,56

    [7] => Finisharray



)
```

I want the value of position 0,3,6. Now the value from 3 i want to convert to int and the value from position 5 into float.

I get value from array with `echo $xml[5]` but i get only string.

$xml is the array

Now the problem is that i have no idea to convert all string to a integer number or a float value.

Any idea?

Comment: So `$xml[50]` is supposed to _be_ that array you have shown us, or what? _"to convert all string to a integer number or a float value"_ - what int or float do you want to get from "converting" `Mytestarray` or `Finish array`?

Comment: You can use `floatval` or `intval` it seems to me not...?

Comment: if i do this echo ``` intval($xml[3])``` i get NULL value

Comment: It's strange behavior. Especially since the present digit is a good integer. On the other hand, you have unconventional number formats for PHP in terms of your floating numbers.

Comment: if i do this
$a = $xml[101];
var_dump($a);

i have this: string(96) "85"

Answer (score 1):

If we assume your array of strings and you don't want to touch actual strings but want to get numbers (for future calculations), this kind of code might help you.

```
$xml = array();
$xml[] = "Mytestarray";
$xml[] = "10";
$xml[] = "2";
$xml[] = "26";
$xml[] = "2";
$xml[] = "1.875.12,00";
$xml[] = "2,56";
$xml[] = "Finisharray";


// For Each Element
foreach($xml as $element)
{
    // Display
    echo "<br />".$element;

    // If String NO Alphabetic
    if(!preg_match("/[A-Z]{".strlen($element)."}/i",$element))  echo " --> ".floatval(str_replace(",",".",str_replace(".","",$element)));
}
// Fin - For Each Element
```

When it is not a string of characters I replace the point by a space and the comma by a point to obtain a convertible string in float

Comment: i have an array named $xml, that contain all value

Comment: @Federico And in my answer...? There is no array named `$xml` with different values...?

Comment: @Federico Does this solution help you...? Or not at all...?